# iPhone EDGE Network Problem

Tags: iphone, network, jailbreak

I have a factory unlocked, not yet jailbroken iphone 3g. I am running ios 4.2.1 and firmware 5.15.04. My problem is that the edge connection keeps getting turned off randomly (rather frequently) and I need to keep toggling the airplane mode to get it back to work. I already tried resetting network settings, resetting all settings, restoring to factory settings and creating a new profile. None of it seems to work. Other iPhone users on Airtel (a carrier in India) are not having this problem. Please let me know if anything could be done?

Comment: This sounds like a warranty usage case.

Comment: Restoring as new in a new user could possibly help if it downloads a new ipsw file that isnt jacked, but pretty much it sounds like warranty time is now.

Comment: @Cawas @hobs: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to forcibly install a new ipsw file?

Comment: hold `shift` (or `option` on a mac) while you press the "*Update*" button on iTunes. It's described in one of the links from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last thing you can try to do before **sending it to repair** is making a new install by [Erasing All Content and Settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2110). There are many ways to accomplish this and many layers of [wiping](http://lifehacker.com/#!395743/completely-erase-your-iphones-data). One of them is through [installing](http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/23/how-to-use-ipsw-files/) a new firmware ([ipsw](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=750)) file just in case the one iTunes download is [somehow corrupted](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1275).

But doing anything beyond the regular Apple way is entirely up to you as the process are even more time consuming and not all that simple.